# Audio from audio source to pipe (stdin/stdout)

Tags: audio, bluetooth, streaming, audio-playback, pulseaudio

I am trying to get an audio stream from Bluetooth to the stdin of [`fm_transmitter`](https://github.com/PNPtutorials/FM_Transmitter_RPi3) on my Raspberry Pi 3 / up-to-date Raspbian Stretch.

> So far, I got FM-Transmitter running with an ICE-Cast-Stream using ffmpeg & my Pi is playing Music from Spotify via bluetooth (I installed `blueman` next to the things I followed from [this Tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-your-Raspberry-Pi-into-a-Portable-Bluetooth-A/)).

To archive this, I tried using `ffmpeg -f s16le -i hw:0 - | fm_transmitter -f 87.6 -` as mentioned in tutorials, and tested with all the other devices listed with `aplay -L`. But it can not listen to any of the sources / can't find it.

So as main concern, I am wondering which tool can link an audio-source to the pipe.

Comment: You can create a named pipe to output to fm transmission.  From there you can create a sink to output to your named pipe: load-module module-pipe-sink file=/named/pipe sink_name=Fm_transmission , then stream to the new sink.

Comment: Sorry, just saw using ffmpeg and stretch. Just assumed you were using pulseaudio when I saw Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` seems not to be able to do what I need and `aplay -L` wasn't capable of finding Bluetooth sources. But with `pactl list sources short` I finally found the A2DP-source.

Anyways, after messing around with `sox`, I finally got an audio signal from default-device to bash, but it was stuttering as I used the following command.

```
$ sox -d -t raw -r 22.05k -b 8 - gain -5 | fm_transmitter -f 87.6 -
```

---

After I thought of the sampling rate at first place being 44.8k, and the piped rate being 22.05k - which is not perfectly dividable - I tried different tempo rates.

I found `tempo 0.97` being fine for me, still it stutters in the first seconds but then it works.

The only issue is, the tempo reduce adds a slight stacking delay - which isn't perfect nor real-time at all.

```
$ sox -d -t raw -b 8 -r 22050 - gain -5 tempo 0.97 | fm_transmitter -f 87.6 -

Playing: stdin, 22050 Hz, 16 bits, mono

Input File     : 'default' (alsa)
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM

In:0.00% 00:07:15.97 [00:00:00.00] Out:9.90M [ =====|===== ] Hd:4.4 Clip:0
```